# Movie about guy raised in a bunker

Tags: story-identification, movie

I am trying to identify a movie that I very vaguely remember from when I was a kid. I'm going to say it was somewhere between late 80s and early 2000s when it came out.

Basically I remember a family (or maybe just a couple) having a barbecue or something when a plane crashes on their house. They see it coming and immediately retreat into an underground fallout bunker the husband built under the house. The wife is pregnant and ends up going into labor that night in the bunker. For some reason they thought the plane crash was actually aliens or a soviet missile strike or something (movie starts in like the 60-70s I think).

Anyway, flash forward 18-20(?) years and they decide that the now young adult son should leave the bunker to find a wife (I distinctly remember a comment about "hopefully one who isn't an alien (or mutant, or something like that)"). He exits the bunker in full hazmat only to come up through a service hatch in an alley. A Blockbuster (or Hollywood video?) has been built in place of the house, and some homeless dude thinks he (the son) is an alien. He ends up falling in love with some blonde chick (who isn't an alien or mutant).

This probably isn't very far into the movie, but I was probably like 8-10 years old when I saw this and very likely fell asleep. This is genuinely all I really remember about the movie, so I hope it makes sense. It is probably more romantic comedy than scifi now that I think about it, but as a kid I always remembered those parts better.

Comment: This film doesn't appear to have any sci-fi content

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### [*Blast from the Past*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blast_from_the_Past_(film)) (1999)

> In 1962, eccentric American scientist Dr. Calvin Webber (Christopher Walken) believes nuclear war with the Soviet Union is imminent, and builds a secret fallout shelter beneath his backyard. Alarmed by the Cuban Missile Crisis, Calvin takes his pregnant wife Helen (Sissy Spacek) into the shelter. Due to a freak mechanical failure causing the pilot of a passing F-86 Sabre fighter jet to lose control and eject, the abandoned plane crashes into the house; Calvin assumes the worst and activates the shelter’s time-locks for 35 years.
>
> [...]
>
> When the shelter unlocks in 1997, Calvin mistakes the now-blighted neighborhood where his home once was for a post-apocalyptic wasteland of irradiated mutants and decides the family must stay underground. With supplies running out and Calvin falling ill, Adam (Brendan Fraser) leaves the shelter for the first time. He meets Melcher, who encountered Calvin the previous night, bursting through the floor in his radiation suit. Melcher now worships Calvin and the elevator.